# What are the difference between different types C/C++ header files

Tags: c++, c, header-files

In the most tradition way, c/c++ uses `.h` for header file extensions. However, in the realworld usage (i.e. Visual C++), there are many other types of header files, such as: `.hxx`, `.hh`, `.w`, `.idl`, etc.

My question is, why people need different types of header files? I don't have a complete list of all the header types I saw, but please pick any case you familiar with and explain a bit.

Comment: I will use .inl for that header's inline methods that I don't want cluttering up my "interface" document, i.e. the .h file.  So at the bottom of MyClass.h I will `#include "MyClass.inl"`

Comment: I've also seen `.hpp`,  and horrifyingly, `.h++`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: `.h++` seems legal.  *q-char-sequence*, used for `#include` filenames is defined by *q-char*:
any member of the source character set except new-line and `"`  Similarly for *h-char-sequence*

Comment: @BenVoigt: yeah, it is completely legal, I just hesitate when I see such characters in filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the compiler there's no difference. You can use the extension that you want, or even no extension at all. So, `.hh`, `.hxx`, `.my_awesome_extension` are valid. The only important thing for the compiler is that it can find a file with the name you specify.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler don't care about the extension, but most of code-editors do and will switch to C++ mode if they encounter one of these extension.

For instance Emacs will use `c-mode` with `.h` extension while switching to `c++-mode` with `.hpp` extension.